# automatically generate/backup a list of files (but not backup the actual files)?

Tags: command-line, files, backup

What would be the best/easiest way for a non-techie like me to get my headless Ubuntu media server to generate a file containing a list of files X-levels deep from a specific folder and back that list up without actually backing up the files themselves?  Ideally (but by no means required) it would be a nicely formatted HTML page... but only if there's some existing tool that does that sort of thing.  I'm not expecting the answerer to write extensive code for me.

I have Crashplan installed but I don't want to use bandwidth moving terabytes of non-critical files to the Cloud.  But in the rare event something happens, I want to at least see a list of what was there so I can see what was lost and I can pick and choose what to replace.

I hope the answer is complete, as I'm by no means a command line guru... and it does need to be command line because it is headless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tree`. It might not be preinstalled, so get it using

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Then you can get a list of your files and their directory structure by simply running

```
$ tree test/
test/
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
├── dir2
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── dir3
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

You redirect the output to a file like this:

```
tree test/ > directory-list.txt
```

You can limit recursion depth using the `-L` option, e.g. `tree -L 3 test/`.

If you want a fancy HTML page with FTP links to each file, `tree` has that built in!

```
tree -H /ftp-root test/ > directory-list.html
```

You need to specify a base link though which will control where all the file hyperlinks point to, as described in the manpage (`man tree`):

```
   -H baseHREF
          Turn  on  HTML output, including HTTP references. Useful for ftp
          sites.  baseHREF gives the base ftp  location  when  using  HTML
          output.  That  is,  the local directory may be `/local/ftp/pub',
          but  it  must   be   referenced   as   `ftp://hostname.organiza‐
          tion.domain/pub'  (baseHREF  should be `ftp://hostname.organiza‐
          tion.domain'). Hint: don't use ANSI lines with this option,  and
          don't give more than one directory in the directory list. If you
          wish to use colors via CCS style-sheet, use  the  -C  option  in
          addition to this option to force color output.
```

The resulting file opened in a webbrowser looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

`find` is your friend here.

Assuming you want to backup all filenames, upto 4 levels deep, starting from `/foo/bar` directory, into a file `backup_filenames.txt`:

```
find /foo/bar -maxdepth 4 -type f >backup_filename.txt
```

To consider only filenames of a certain extension e.g. `.txt`, use `-name`:

```
find /foo/bar -maxdepth 4 -type f -name '*.txt' >backup_filename.txt
```

Case insensitively (`-iname`):

```
find /foo/bar -maxdepth 4 -type f -iname '*.txt' >backup_filename.txt
```

Modify the parameters to meet your need. Also check `man find`.

Comment: Thanks!  And then I'd set up a cron job to do that periodically, right?

Comment: @bcsteeve Yes, you absolutely can. Note that, `>` truncates the file so make any necessary modifications on the backup filename logic, if needed.

Comment: If you want HTML output, you can use something like `awk` to format the output from find: `find /foo/bar -maxdepth 4 -type f | awk 'BEGIN {print "<html><body><pre>"} {printf "%s<br>", $0} END {print "</pre></body></html>"}' > backup_filename.html`